# Eventos múltiples usando do while

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

presento el siguiente problema con eventos en javascript, lo que deseo hacer es tener varios efectos de fondo (cambio de colores) usando eventos de ratón como "mouseout", "mouseover" & "click", intento hacerlo dinámico haciendo uso del bucle do while.

En la consola del navegador no me aparecen errores, pero simplemente no se ejecuta nada.

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente, tengo una variable llamada evento la cual es un arreglo que contiene puros valores de tipo cadena, es decir, contiene los nombres de los eventos que deseo ejecutar sobre mi documento html, a este arreglo lo recorro con un bucle do while, con if me aseguro que cuando el array tome el valor dinámico de su posición se ejecute el efecto que deseo que se muestre, un if por cada evento.

De momento no he podido solucionarlo, me gustaría si pudiesen apoyarme con este problema, de antemano un saludo.

```
let evento=['mouseout','mouseover','click'];
evento=document.querySelector('.navegadores');
let longitud_evento=evento.length;
let iterar=0;

do{
   if(evento[iterar]=='mouseout'){
       evento.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
        evento.style.backgroundColor='black';
        evento.style.color='yellow';
    });
}else{
    if(evento[iterar]=='mouseover'){
        evento.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
            evento.style.backgroundColor='pink';
            evento.style.color='black';
        });
    }else{
        if(evento[iterar]=='click'){
            evento.addEventListener('click',function(){
                evento.style.backgroundColor='red';
                evento.style.color='white';
            });
        }
    }
  }
}
```

while(iterar>longitud_evento);

Comment: Imagino que no ejecuta nada, porque a tu variable _evento_, la estas reasignando con `document.querySelector('.navegadores')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pude encontrar la solución a este problema, comparto con ustedes dicha solución, esperando que pueda aportar algo a la comunidad y a las personas que por primera vez se inician en este lenguaje (JS).

La solución es la siguiente:

He creado una estructura HTML básica, la cual contiene una sección y un div interno, dicho div a su vez contiene una imagen, un h2 como título y dos párrafos, la idea es ejecutar diferentes efectos de fondo, tipo de letra y color de letra al momento de hacer algun movimiento con el puntero del ratón, a estas acciones las conozco como eventos de mouse, las cuales se pueden ejecutar con la función de JS llamada "addEventListener".

Para dichas acciones o eventos, la solución que propongo es la siguiente, que dichos efectos se ejecuten mediante bucles anidados, en esta primer solución he usado como ciclo padre un "do while", que a su vez, contiene otro ciclo, un "while", el ciclo hijo ("while") ejecutará de manera dinámica cada uno de los eventos de ratón, los cuales son, 'click', 'dblclick', 'mouseout', 'mouseleave', estos eventos estan contenidos en un array, el cual recibe el nombre de "evento" que, mediante el "while" el contenido de dicho array llamado "evento" se recorrerá mediante una variable llamada iteración, la cual su función es vaciar el contenido del array.

Después el array que será vaciado por la variable llamada iteración, la cual se evaluará con un if para determinar el valor que contiene la posición de dicho array, de acuerdo al valor numérico de cada posición que tome de manera dinámica la variable iteración se ejecutará un evento de ratón en particular, estos efectos se aplicarán a un bloque de código, que a su vez, afectarán a más elementos contenidos por dicho bloque.

Las propiedades dinámicas que cada elemento html tomará son las siguientes: "tipo de letra", "color de letra", "color de fondo" y "fondo de pantalla".

El fragmento de código que hace posible este efecto, básico pero interesante es el siguiente.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Eventos JS</title>
</head>

<body>
   <section>
       <div id="eventos">
           <img alt="AS3" src="img/as3_.png" />
           <h2>ActionScript 3</h2>
           <p>Es el lenguaje de programación de la plataforma Adobe Flash.</p>
           <p>Originalmente desarrollado como una forma para que los desarrolladores programen de forma más interactiva.</p>
       </div>
   </section>

   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/evento.js"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
var evento=['mouseout','mouseleave','click','dblclick'];
var ejecuta_evento=document.querySelector('#eventos');
var iteracion=0;
var longitudEvento=evento.length;

do{
    while(iteracion<longitudEvento){
        if(evento[iteracion]=='mouseout'){
            ejecuta_evento.addEventListener('mouseout',()=>{
            ejecuta_evento.style.backgroundColor='#9D43F0';
            ejecuta_evento.style.color='#F06651';
            ejecuta_evento.style.fontFamily="'Monaco',Verdana,Consolas";
            ejecuta_evento.style.fontSize='2em';
        });
    }else{
        if(evento[iteracion]=='mouseleave'){
            ejecuta_evento.addEventListener('mouseleave',()=>{
                ejecuta_evento.style.backgroundColor='#F06651';
                ejecuta_evento.style.color='#9D43F0';
                ejecuta_evento.style.fontFamily="Monaco',Verdana,Consolas";
                ejecuta_evento.style.fontSize='2em';
            });
        }else{
            if(evento[iteracion]=='click'){
                ejecuta_evento.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                    ejecuta_evento.style.backgroundColor='#F8D732';
                    ejecuta_evento.style.color='#4344D9';
                    ejecuta_evento.style.fontFamily="Monaco',Verdana,Consolas";
                    ejecuta_evento.style.fontSize='2em';
                });
            }else{
                if(evento[iteracion]=='dblclick'){
                    ejecuta_evento.addEventListener('dblclick',()=>{
                        ejecuta_evento.style.backgroundColor='#4344D9';
                        ejecuta_evento.style.color='#F8D732';
                        ejecuta_evento.style.fontFamily="Monaco',Verdana,Consolas";
                        ejecuta_evento.style.fontSize='2em';
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    iteracion +=1;
   }
}
while(iteracion>longitudEvento);
```

Estos son los efectos que visuales que se muestran a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La siguiente solución para resolver el mismo problema es el siguiente:

Comparto la modificación que código JS que permite realizar los mismos efectos visuales, (el código HTML no se modifica, siguie siendo el mismo).

JavaScript

```
var evento=['mouseout','mouseleave','click','dblclick'];
var ejecuta_evento=document.querySelector('#eventos');
var iteracion=0;
var longitudEvento=evento.length;

do{
evento.forEach(function(iterar){
    ejecuta_evento.addEventListener(iterar,()=>{
        if(iterar=='mouseout'){
            ejecuta_evento.style.backgroundColor='#9D43F0';
            ejecuta_evento.style.color='#F06651';
            ejecuta_evento.style.fontFamily="Monaco',Verdana,Consolas";
            ejecuta_evento.style.fontSize='2em';
        }else if(iterar=='mouseleave'){
            ejecuta_evento.style.backgroundColor='#F06651';
            ejecuta_evento.style.color='#9D43F0';
            ejecuta_evento.style.fontFamily="Monaco',Verdana,Consolas";
            ejecuta_evento.style.fontSize='2em';
        }else if(iterar=='click'){
            ejecuta_evento.style.backgroundColor='#F8D732';
            ejecuta_evento.style.color='#4344D9';
            ejecuta_evento.style.fontFamily="Monaco',Verdana,Consolas";
            ejecuta_evento.style.fontSize='2em';
        }else if(iterar=='dblclick'){
            ejecuta_evento.style.backgroundColor='#4344D9';
            ejecuta_evento.style.color='#F8D732';
            ejecuta_evento.style.fontFamily="Monaco',Verdana,Consolas";
            ejecuta_evento.style.fontSize='2em';
        }
    });
});
}
while(iteracion>longitudEvento);
```

Espero que este pequeño aporte sea de utilidad, de antemano gracias por el tiempo dedicado a leer este artículo.